# Mac mini Mx + Studio display simple power solution

Tags: thunderbolt, mac-mini, power

I have a pretty full desk including a Mac mini M1 and a new Apple Studio Display. Despite it being smaller than my MBP, I understand that the mini can't draw its power from the Studio Display despite the promise of Thunderbolt.

Is there really no way to simplify the cable situation at least? Is there really no way to power this combination from a single power outlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Just because the Mini has Thunderbolt ports does not mean that it can be powered through them. They are designed for down-stream power supply only.

Just use an extension strip (a decent one, with surge protection) and some cable ties.